# Overlapping content (css and div blocks)

Tags: jquery, html, css, countdownevent

I am customising a responsive website for a event so I added a countdown with jquery only the problem is that I have 2 css overlapping and the countdown is not good positioned.

Can someone help me to positioned the countdown and find the css code for the countdown in bootstrap.min.css so I can place it in my main.css

All the code is in the source (It is pretty messy, sorry for that).

Hope some one can help. Thanks!

[futuremoney.nl/worldofsummer](http://futuremoney.nl/worldofsummer)

Comment: "Find the CSS-Code" -> Right-Click on Element and Inspect Element with Firebug(Firefox) or something similar with Chrome.

Comment: in sonorama.css find this .countdown-container then change top:50% to 60%, easy solution but it is really bad design

Comment: it is still overlaping

Comment: sonorama.css line 1207 change top to `top:20%;` but will will need to make other changes in your media queries for smaller screens

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find things like these easily in the inspectors most (if not all) browsers come packed with these days:

[image: SCREENSHOT]

You can live edit your CSS.

Comment: i have edidet it and uploaded but if i load it in my browser it goes back to 50%
.countdown-container {
 position: relative;
 top: 20%;
 -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
 -moz-transform: translateY(-50%);
 transform: translateY(-50%);
}

Comment: Looks good here... try hard refreshing/clearing your local cache

Comment: do you know how to line it out on smaller screens?

Comment: by using media queries. Although this thing just isn't going to be pretty on small screens without putting a lot of work into it. Best give the container a min-width. That way it will stick out of the viewport maybe, but the 'clocks' will not stack on top of eachother.